# Does ISO 8601 specify a default time and timezone for dates?

Tags: datetime

When an ISO 8610-formatted date is provided without any time or timezone information (e.g. '2015-04-16'), is it correct to assume that it refers to midnight at the start of the day in the local time zone, or midnight at the start of the day in UTC (i.e. 'T00:00:00+00:00' or 'T00:00:00Z' as the default suffix), or something else?

Comment: The behaviour in _JavaScript_ seems to be _UTC_ `new Date('2015-04-16').toISOString(); // 2015-04-16T00:00:00.000Z` _(I'm currently on GMT+1 locally)_

Comment: PHP seems to use the local timezone: `print (new DateTime('2015-04-16'))->format(DATE_ATOM); // 2015-04-16T00:00:00-04:00`